# find the directories not in argument list

Tags: shell, scripting

I need to find the directories not in the list.

Suppose I have the following directories:

```
opt
cmd
XX
```

I need to get all the directories not in the above 3.

Comment: What is your working environment? Which OS?

Comment: Get all the directories where? All the subdirectories of the current directory? Where is the list stored: in a file?

Answer (score 2):

With `find`:

```
find /path -maxdepth 1 -not \( -name "opt" -or -name "cmd" -or -name "XX" \)
```

- `-maxdepth 1` will not descend into subdirectories; not recursive
- `-not \( ... \)` negates all within the brackets

  - `-name ... -or -name ...`: the names you want to exclude connected with an `-or`

---

Another approach could be with finds `-regex`, where you can put all exclude directories in one pattern:

```
find /path -maxdepth 1 -not -regex ".*/opt\|.*/cmd\|.*/XX"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the shell you are using you can try for `bash`:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -ld /!(opt|mnt|XX)
```

Assuming that these directories reside in the root (`/`) directory. Otherwise omit the `/` character.

Comment: This needs `extglob`